# How can I store an output print data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit, praw

My script prints top 5 subreddits from specified redditor.

```
reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id="",
    client_secret="",
    password="",
    user_agent="",
    username="",
)


for submission in reddit.redditor("").top(limit=5):
    print(submission.subreddit)
```

Im trying to store in txt file what is being printed.

I was trying to use this method:

```
f = open('file.txt', 'w+')
f.write(submission.subreddit)
f.close()
```

But received this error at the end

*TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Subreddit*

Any ideas how can I store subreddits in txt file?

Comment: Use "str" to convert the output: `f.write(str(submission.subreddit))`. "print" does this internally.

Comment: It worked but saves only one line of text and should more. Is there any option to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing something to a file, but the something is not a string, you need to first convert it to a string.

```
str_subreddit = str(submission.subreddit)
```

However, there are better ways of doing what you're trying to do:

- Use Unix shell to redirect output of your program to a file: `python my_script.py > file.txt`

  - To append instead of overwriting, use `>>`
  - This is arguably a better method, because it follows the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy)
- `print` takes a `file` argument: `print(str_subreddit, file=f)`

  - You will of course have to open the file at the beginning of your program

Also, if you are trying to append to a file with `f = open('file.txt', 'w+')`, you want `a` not `w+`. `w+` is something else.